# How can I change an image with onMouseOver on an area shape?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polygon, imagemap

I have this:

```
<div class="map_container">

  <%= image_tag("maps/mainmap.png", :width => "450", :height => "450", :usemap => "#mainmap", :alt => "") %>  

  <map name="mainmap">

    <area shape="poly" 
      coords="158,43,152,49,164,86,165,112,153,153,139,169,145,236,201,241,202,251,166,253,142,257,132,294,102,269,85,240,68,227,53,213,28,202,27" alt=""
      onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='pointer'" 
      onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" >
  </map>              
</div>
```

Which alters the cursor when I move the mouse onto the area shape, but how can I make it change the image (mainmap.png) being displayed?

**edit**

I've tried the following:

`onmouseover="this.src='image2.png';"` which doesn't work, but I can only get the original image to display using the rails image_tag helper, the line: `<img src="maps/mainmap.png" width="450" height="450" usemap="#mainmap" alt="">` also doesn't display the mainmap.png image. So is this a problem with my app finding the dir of the image?

Thanks very much for any help its much appreciated.

Comment: onmouseover="this.src='image2.png';"

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are not using any js framework, so try this:

```
function changeImage(area) {
    var parent= area.parentNode, // Get the parent of area
        name = parent.getAttribute('name'), // Get the name attribute of the area which is same as the id of the image used
        img = document.getElementById(name); // Get the image obj

    img.src = "maps/newmap.png"; // Set the new image source
}
```